# Unable to call jasper through java code

Tags: java

I am creating one jasper file using ireport tool and trying to call it from java code but it can't be call, but whenever i am call an existing jasper file which already in project through java code then jasper file is generated. one more thing when i am use existing .jasper file and modify the design of it even though the report is generated in previous format. I don't know what to do, please guide me

Comment: Please post your current code that you are using to access the Jasper files. Show where it is working and where it is not. We need a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)